# Can off policy evaluation (OPE) like doubly robust show a reward estimation outside the range of the max/min reward? Why?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am trying to learn a policy through offline Reinforcement Learning (RL).

After convergence (looking at expected cumulative reward), I used *Doubly Robust* to estimate the estimated value of the policy. My reward metric is `[-100, 100]`, but doubly robust shows a reward of `~500` (`sd=100`). The [Elliptical Copula Regression](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.08551) (ECR) shows a reward of 60.

Is that possible? If so, how? Or does that mean I have some error in implementation?

I tried to implement the doubly robust following [Dr. Burnskill's method](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00923).